# Cast NSObject of Strings to [String]

Tags: swift, casting, nsobject

I'm stuck trying to cast an NSObject of strings to [String].
I'm using coreData and my transformable is an NSObject. The annoying thing is that it is not enumerable. So my usual tricks do not work.
Could anyone help me out?

Thanks

```
{(
  dried,
  stewed
)}
```

This should turn into this:

```
[dried, stewed].
```

Usual downcasting does not work:

```
  myObject as! [String] :(
```

Also I noticed that sometimes the error message says it cannot downcast the NSObject and sometimes it says:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSetI' (0x10f101138) to 'NSArray' (0x10f101598).
```

EDIT:
I found a workaround:

```
let mySet = myObject as! NSSet
let myArr : [String] =  mySet.map { $0 as! String } . // yay!
```

I first cast it to a set to make it enumerable and then I cast it to [String]

What is interesting is that this does not work:

```
let mySet = myObject as! NSSet 
let myArr = mySet as! [String] // nope.
```

Comment: Add Your Coredata model class in Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set and Array are not the same type, you cannot just cast them to each other.

Ideally, you should cast the Objective-C type `NSSet` to Swift `Set`:

```
let mySet = myObject as! Set<String>
```

If iteration is your only purpose, then this is all you need.

If you really need an array, create a new array from the set:

```
let myArray = Array(mySet)
```

Answer (score 0):

If myObject is a set (a relationship in your core data model) then try doing

```
let arr:[String] = Array(myObject) as! [String]
```

Comment: Alas: Argument type 'NSObject' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'

Comment: @ArneOldenhave, is it `FoodEntity` that coresponds to `myObject` or it is one of the attributes like `tags`?

Comment: It is the tags object

Comment: I think I foud a way

Comment: @ArneOldenhave if it works please post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, I did not know I could do that

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
let mySet = myObject as! NSSet
let myArr : [String] =  mySet.map { $0 as! String } . // yay!
```

I first cast it to a set to make it enumerable and then I cast it to [String]

What is interesting is that this does not work:

```
let mySet = myObject as! NSSet 
let myArr = mySet as! [String] // nope.
```